# How to pass parameter to controller using laravel data table?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I need to pass id to my controller function via laravel datatable i.e yajra datatable,
i need to recive id in my function to fetch data but its not posting at all.
I have tried many ways but no luck

below is my code,

jquery,

```
$(function() {
      var id = "<?php echo $id;?>";
      // alert(id);
      var table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          searchable:true,
          ajax: "{{ route('vendor.getOperationTimes') }}",
          // type:"GET",
          // data: {
          //   "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content'),
          //   "id": id
          // },
          columns: [{
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex'
                },
              {
                  data: 'name',
                  name: 'name'
              },
              {
                  data: 'day',
                  name: 'day'
              },
              {
                  data: 'start_time',
                  name: 'start_time'
              },
              {
                  data: 'end_time',
                  name: 'end_time'
              },
              {
                  data: 'action',
                  name: 'action',
                  orderable: false,
                  searchable: false
              },
          ]
      });
```

controller function,

```
public function getOperationTimes(Request $request)
    {
        
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $station_id = $request['id'];

            // echo $station_id;exit;
            $station = new Station();
            $getData = $station->getOperationTimes($station_id);
            return Datatables::of($getData)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href=/eCharge/public/vendor/getOperationTime/<?php echo $getData->id;?>" class="delete btn btn-danger">Edit</a> ';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
```

route,

```
 Route::get('getOperationTimes',[VendorStationController::class, 'getOperationTimes'])->name('getOperationTimes');
```

please help me someone at the earliest

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('getOperationTimes/{id}')

ajax: "{{ route('vendor.getOperationTimes', ['id' => id]) }}",
```

You can try above code.